# Symfony3: Enable aptoma twig-markdown extension

Tags: twig, markdown, symfony, twig-extension

How can I enable the [aptoma twig-markdown extension](https://github.com/aptoma/twig-markdown)? I have installed it using `composer` but when I use `{% markdown %}` in my twig file, I get an error message saying:

> Unexpected "markdown" tag (expecting closing tag for the "block" tag
>   defined near line 8).

I had a look in the symfony documentation but was not able to find the solution.

Edit:

I tried to add the following code to `services.yml` but got another error:

```
twig.markdown:
    class: Aptoma\Twig\Extension\MarkdownExtension
    arguments: []
    tags:
        - { name: twig.extension }
```

> Type error: Argument 1 passed to
>   Aptoma\Twig\Extension\MarkdownExtension::__construct() must be an
>   instance of Aptoma\Twig\Extension\MarkdownEngineInterface, none given
>   [...]

Upon request my `.twig`-file:

```
{% extends 'XYZBundle::layout.html.twig' %}

{% block title %}
    {{ parent() }} – Eintrag anzeigen
{% endblock %}

{% block platform_body %}
    <ul>
        <li>
            <a href="{{ path('work_index') }}">Back to the list</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="{{ path('work_edit', { 'id': work.id }) }}">Edit</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <h1>{{ work.title }}</h1>

    <div class="work-content">
    {% markdown %}
    {{ work.content }}
    {% endmarkdown %}
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 2):

According to the docs you need to install the markdown engine of your choice like:

```
composer require michelf/php-markdown
```

You need to create a service for the twig extension and the markdown engine, add the engine to the extension and register it as twig extension, f.e like this in your services.yml or config.yml:

```
services:
    markdown.engine:
        class: Aptoma\Twig\Extension\MarkdownEngine\MichelfMarkdownEngine
    twig.markdown:
        class: Aptoma\Twig\Extension\MarkdownExtension
        arguments: ['@markdown.engine']
        tags:
            - { name: twig.extension }
```

Symfony will then automatically register it as twig extension through the usage of 'tags' or tagged services.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! However, when I am using this code I get the following error message: `Attempted to load class "MarkdownEngine" from namespace "Aptoma\Twig\Extension".
Did you forget a "use" statement for another namespace?`

Comment: sorry the class path was wrong, i corrected it. also note the added composer command

Comment: I really appreciate your help. When I am using it like `{{ "# Heading Level 1"|markdown }}` it works but when I use `{% markdown %}{% endmarkdown %}` I get an error message saying `Unknown "markdown" tag.`. Can you tell me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: can you post the whole code block, this sounds suspicous: expecting closing tag for the "block" tag defined near line 8

Comment: I just saw that I was also using the knp-markdown-bundle which also provides the iinline-`markdown` command in twig. Maybe there is a conflict between this bundle and the aptoma twig-extension or the aptoma twig-extension service is not registered correctly. I think it could be the second cause since the inline-`markdown` command works but imho only because the knp-markdown-bundle provides this command.

Answer (score 1):

According to the new autowire system, you only have to declare the mardown engine implementing the Aptoma markdown engine interface.

```
Aptoma\Twig\Extension\MarkdownEngineInterface:
    class: the markdown engine of your choice!

twig.extension.markdown:
    class: Aptoma\Twig\Extension\MarkdownExtension
    tags:
        - { name: twig.extension }
```

If you do **not** change `Aptoma\Twig\Extension\MarkdownEngineInterface`by something like `markdown.engine` you do **not** need to declare arguments in your twig extension service declaration.

If you want to use the recommended markdown engine, install it via:

`composer require michelf/php-markdown`

Then, declare it:

```
Aptoma\Twig\Extension\MarkdownEngineInterface:
    class: Aptoma\Twig\Extension\MarkdownEngine\MichelfMarkdownEngine 

twig.extension.markdown:
    class: Aptoma\Twig\Extension\MarkdownExtension
    tags:
        - { name: twig.extension }
```

You can see in `vendor\aptoma` subdirectories the available engine. 
[image: The available engine]

But you can use yours. It only have to implement `MarkdownEngineInterface`.